# Incorrect grammar versus different dialects

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, american-english, dialects, pennsylvanian-english

My girlfriend, someone from southern New Jersey, constantly says phrases like "I'm done my homework" or "I'm done my dinner."  I try to correct her and say, "I'm done with my homework" or "I'm done with my dinner," but she insists this is what she has always said.

Is her grammar just plain incorrect, or is this allowed if she actually has a different dialect where everyone in the region says the same thing?

Comment: A New Englander here, and I've heard this quite a bit. I think it's just another example of a distinction that survives amongst a few verbs in English, namely that between auxiliary *to have* versus *to be* with past participles. *I have done* expresses having done something in the past at one point, while *I am done* expresses a state of being recently finished with a *particular* instance of doing. I see nothing at all wrong with *I'm done my work*, and the only reason to avoid it in formal writing is that it's not totally dialect-neutral. Of course, I probably wouldn't say *I'm done it*...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd put this in the same category as "ain't".

While regularly used in conversation, I'd never use it in any written paper.

Ask her if that's how she would write it should she be writing a formal document.

Spoken language is generally more flexible, and I'm wondering if she doesn't mean "I've done my homework" and due to accent it sounds like "I'm", because "I've done my homework" would be proper English.

---

### Edit to add more information

"I did my homework" is correct using simple past form of "do".

"I have done my homework" is correct using present perfect tense form of "do".

"I am done with my home work" (or "I'm", being a contraction of I am) is using "done" as an adjective, the verb is am (first-person singular present indicative of be).

"I'm done my homework" is just wrong. Done is being used as an adjective (I am done), and "my homework" is an incomplete clause.

Either you must remove the verb am and replace "done" with "did", or add the word "with" to link "my homework" to the statement.

The only way this could possibly be correct, is if people are pronouncing the "ve" of "I've done my homework" as an "m" for some odd reason. "I've done my homework" is proper (I have done my homework).

On an unrelated note, I agree Jay's answer philosophically.

Comment: Sometimes I'll say "I'm done my homework?" to which she says, "Yes. I am done my homework."

Comment: Ok yeah, ask her if she'd actually write that on a formal document. If she says no, then you have her opinion on if it's proper English. Then it's just a matter of spoken language having a habit, like "Ain't". Spoken language is very flexible, and different regions have different "improper" standards, but writing standards are generally the same in most places (minus the whole color vs colour controversy :p)

Comment: I wouldn't put it in the same category as *ain't* — most people are familiar with "ain't"; few with "I'm done my…".

Comment: @ShreevatsaR It's regional. Most people aren't familiar with Singlish either, because only the few million people in Singapore and those who've encountered it know about it. Singlish has lots of improper English. When talking to their friends online they use it, but when writing formal papers they use proper English. When listening to them speak, I could understand it half the time, but the other times I'd have to say "Did you mean X or Y"?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say spoken language is "more flexible", although I think I know what you actually mean by that.  I would say that spoken language is a living, evolving thing, and standard/written language conservatively changes based on some of those things, and resists other changes.  The only reason I am making this point is because the spoken systems, while different from Standard English, are rule-based and systematic themselves; so I just wanted to emphasize that.

Comment: I would love to hear @Brett Allen explain in what way "I'm done my dinner" is not standard grammar.  I'm from Pittsburgh, and it is not standard there, but my Philadelphia friends all use the phrase.  What is the non-standard aspect?  Transitive v non-transitive verbs?  Auxiliaries?

Comment: "I did my homework" is correct using simple past form of "do". 

"I have done my homework" is correct using present perfect tense form of "do". 

"I am done with my home work" and (I'm being a contraction of I am) is using "done" as an adjective, the verb is am (first-person singular present indicative of be).

"I'm done my homework" is just wrong. Done is being used as an adjective (I am done), and "my homework" is an incomplete clause.

Either you must remove the verb am, or add the word "with" to link "my homework" to the statement.

Comment: The only way this could possibly be correct, is if people are pronouncing the "ve" of "I've done my homework" as an "m" for some odd reason. "I've done my homework" is proper (I have done my homework). Does this help @aez ?

Comment: Thanks @Brett Allen, that helps very much.  Now I can confidently tell my Philadelphia friends that they are wrong.  : )

Answer (score 8):

It is not really a matter of being "allowed" to use non-standard grammar: there is no law, as far as I know. It may very well be so that this is part of some dialect. However, non-standard grammar is often advised against by those who use standard grammar. That is why she might want to learn the standard construction too—at least well enough to be able to use it in job interviews etc.

Comment: Good plan Cerberus, I'll start drafting the English Usage Act...

Comment: @Orbling: Yay, that is a prescriptivist's ehh... special dream!

Comment: @Cerberus: Only stumbling block is the question of remedies.  Lifetime incarceration for saying *a'ight* out loud?

Comment: @Orbling: I like your "remedies". Though the benefits of incarceration are beyond doubt, we might also consider putting them away in special dialectical reservations.

Comment: @Cerberus: Aye, penal colonies for the dialectically challenged.  Trouble is England's traditional facilities are somewhat overrun these days.

Comment: @Orbling: Well, there is a thing called prioritisation: since we haven't the space to detain any petty criminal, perhaps we should put linguistic felons in the cells of rapists and murderers and the like, who could be put on a waiting list while they go back home.

Comment: @Cerberus: Well, most of the linguistic felons I know are home.  Just a question of finding a new one to relocate them too.  I think the rapists and murderers have suffered enough.

Comment: @Orbling: Haha, you couldn't be more right!

Comment: The problem here is defining "standard grammar".

Comment: @T.E.D.: Yes, some arbitrary definition must be used. It is usually close to what most intellectuals will consider "proper" grammar, even if they will sometimes deviate from it themselves.

Comment: @Cerberus - Ah...so we just have to wait for intellectuals to agree on it? No problem. I'll wait right here...

Comment: @T.E.D.: Do you have a better definition? It seems to work well enough in practice. If you say no such thing as standard English exists, I believe you are throwing away a useful concept. I say it exists just as much as other abstract things, like *common sense* and *secularization*, hard though they may be to define.

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of a very interesting question.

> When does incorrect English usage become a dialect?

The answer to which I would guess, is when a whole lot of people use it "incorrectly" for a sustained period.

If it is acceptable within a group, but not the whole - it is dialectical.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your more general question, I think you should respect her dialect. Adults should not have their spoken grammar corrected unless they somehow asked for it.

"English" is made up of a whole bunch of more-or-less mutually intelligible dialects. Things that are perfectly proper in one dialect may sound wrong to to people who weren't raised in that dialect. However, if you "correct" someone's speech to match your dialect, what you are effectively saying is "My dialect is better than yours."

Comment: Was going to add an answer, but it's really only comment worthy (if that).   I think she's flat-out wrong, regardless of dialect - but if you want to keep your girlfriend, quit saying so.   Or, more generally (with other people), most of the time you should just let it go, as a matter of social graces.

Comment: @hunter2 That's a good policy. In my life I've frankly lost count of the number of times I did just this, only to find out *I* was the one who would have been wrong. IMHO this would be one of those cases for you. Otherwise, have fun going to New Orleans and telling all 1.2 million residents are "wrong" when they say they are "making groceries". And don't even get me started on "pop" vs. "soda"...

Comment: "Pop"?   Blasphemy!   As long as I can eat some gumbo first ...

Answer (score 2):

I'm from Philadelphia (South Jersey's population is all Philadelphia run-off), and I say "I'm done my work" and similar phrases all the time, and so does everyone around me.  It means "I have finished my work," not that you are fed up with your work, etc., and it is a completely acceptable phrase in the Mid-Atlantic region of America. I only recently discovered that people in other parts of the country don't say it, which is a real shock to me.  I would not write this phrase in a formal paper, since I am an English major (although I would put it in an email). People in Canada and Scotland even say "I'm finished my work," but I wouldn't. It's just a matter of where you grew up. So don't be so hard on your girlfriend.

Comment: To pinpoint the geographical distribution further, this is not seen in NYC dialect or North Jersey.

Answer (score 1):

On the bigger question: Language is a funny thing: "right" is largely determined by what is commonly used. Every now and then some pedantic person says, "99% of speakers of the language think that this word means X, but really it means Y." But such a statement is meaningless. If almost everyone agrees that a word means X, then by definition, that's what it means. This is very different from, say, science: No matter how many people believe that the world is flat or that there are only 4 elements, that doesn't make it so.

That said, I think there are two kinds of language rules. Some are purely convention, like definitions of words. On these there is no "right" beyond common usage. Others have logic behind them, like when to use nominative versus objective case, subject-verb agreement, etc. These cannot be so easily changed without creating logical inconsistences.

Comment: how are those second kinds of rules not convention? They're just a different kind of rule established by convention.

Comment: @Mitch: What I had in mind was this: Ask "Who's there?" and people often say "It's me". They should say "It's I", because the pronoun is a predicate nominative. If you accept "It's me" as correct, but you still use "I" for nominatives and "me" for objectives elsewhere, then you have created a logical inconsistency. The rules no longer hang together. But on the other hand, if people started, say, using the word "puppy" to refer to the young of any domesticated animal, there is no "other case" that this is tied to, so it doesn't create an inconsistency. (continued)

Comment: (continued) You could, of course, change the "related" rules wholesale. If we abolished the word "I" and used "me" whenever you referred to yourself, whether in the nominative or the objective, then the rules would again be consistent.

Comment: I still can't come up with a convincing argument for how any rule is not by some convention. You logically apply the rule for nominative; you logically apply the rule for 'puppy' (young dog). What the rule is is made up by convention (you use 'I' in nominative positions, or the rule 1st positions (allowing 'It's me')). 'puppy' could by convention mean young dogs (as it currently is). Not following the convention consistently could be a mistake or it could be evidence of a different convention. Whether it is what case something should be or what lexical choice, still convention.

Comment: @Mitch: Sure, both kinds of rules are only true by convention. What I'm trying to say is that some rules have logic to them: e.g. it makes sense to say that a plural noun goes with a plural verb. In a very real sense, it would be illogical to say that plural nouns should go with singular verbs. Other rules are more arbitrary, like the definition of a word. Or the rule that a sentence must normally have a subject and a predicate. A sentence with no predicate doesn't convey a complete thought. The rule makes logical sense. (continued)

Comment: (continued) On the flip side, I can't think of any logical argument why the opposite of "cold" should be "hot" and not, say, "frambrack". I can't think of any logical reason why the letter "m" must be pronounced as it is and not, say, as a guttural clicking noise. Or in English, it is conventional to put adjectives before a noun; in Latin adjectives typically come after the noun. There's no logical reason why one rule is better than the other, it's just a convention. So some rules are based on a logical concept, while others are purely a convention.

Answer (score 1):

The *done my homework* construction is a widespread characteristic of Canadian English, and it is also found in the United States, especially among speakers in Northern New England, the Philadelphia area, Southern New Jersey, Delaware and Maryland. There is some variation across dialects in terms of what verbs speakers allow in this construction. Finished and done are the most common verbs accepted in this construction, but some speakers can also use started (as in, “I’m started dinner”).

As for the grammar behind this construction (for speakers who have it), a phrase such as “I’m done my homework” may seem similar to a sentence like “I have done my homework.” However, it has been argued that it is actually more similar to sentences where a form of be is followed by an adjective phrase such as “ready for school.” For example, both of these phrases can be modified by all, as in, “I’m all ready for school” or  “I’m all done my homework.” In contrast, something like “I have all done my homework” is generally ungrammatical for English speakers.

For some more information on this construction, check out the discussion of this phenomenon on the Done my homework page at our Yale Grammatical Diversity Project website: https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/done-my-homework.

Comment: Every single post of yours so far has been an excellent and informed contribution to this site. But please be careful that you are not self-promoting your own website with every posting, as it looks bad and may cause users to flag your posts as spam.

Answer (score 0):

If she insists on using, "I'm done my homework," and she wants to be understood then it's better to restrict its usage to those people fully conversant with the lingo. Otherwise, some will hear, "I've done my homework," meaning it's finished and complete, while others will hear, "I'm done with my homework," meaning that I'm fed up with it and have no intention to work on it further.

The important point is that these two meanings are almost complete opposites.

Comment: "I'm done with my homework" could certainly mean (and usually so) "I've finished my homework". It does not necessarily convey a sense of frustration, except the tone indicates such.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, what decides the grammaticality of some phrase is whether or not the other person can understand what is being said. While not technically correct in "Standard English" (which, by the way, is a very dubious and arbitrary thing), this could easily be correct simply because it sounds natural to her and the community from which she came. It may not sound natural to you, but what sounds natural is largely dependent on the dialect one speaks.

*Prescriptively*, she is not correct; i.e., according to the very arbitrary rules that the Standard puts forth, she is in the wrong. But then again, neither is most spoken language since it is not the same thing as written language (where rules are more often enforced). *Descriptively*--or according to the fact that this is an accepted construction within her community and the individuals' mental grammars--she is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Canadianism - in Canadian English, this is considered grammatically correct.

Growing up in Toronto, I always found it perfectly natural to say things like 'I'm done my dinner' and 'Are you done your homework?'. It wasn't until I started University and met a bunch of Americans that it was pointed out to me as something unusual or incorrect. Here, for example, saying 'I'm done my homework' would indicate that you've completed it; 'I'm done with my homework' implies that you have given up on doing it for the time being, without necessarily completing it.

There's actually mention of it on the Canadian English Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_English#Grammar). It seems to be spreading down to the Northeastern United States.

Comment: When you say "Canadianism," do you mean "eastern Canadianism"? I lived in Calgary for two years (grades 11 and 12) and I don't remember anyone using the wording "I'm done my test," etc. (It's possible that I simply didn't notice it or that I've forgotten, but generally I was very aware of differences between Alberta usage and the U.S. [Texas] usage I had grown up with.)